# kubelet won't start after kuberntes/manifest update

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, cni

This is sort of strange behavior in our K8 cluster.

When we try to deploy a new version of our applications we get:

```
Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "<container-id>" network for pod "application-6647b7cbdb-4tp2v": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "application-6647b7cbdb-4tp2v_default" network: Get "https://[10.233.0.1]:443/api/v1/namespaces/default": dial tcp 10.233.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

I used `kubectl get cs` and found `controller` and `scheduler` in `Unhealthy` state.

As describer [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93472) updated `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml` and
`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` by commenting `--port=0`

When I checked `systemctl status kubelet` it was working.

```
Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-10-26 13:18:46 +0530; 1 years 0 months ago
```

I had restarted kubelet service and `controller` and `scheduler` were shown healthy.

But `systemctl status kubelet` shows (soon after restart kubelet it showed running state)

```
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-11-11 10:50:49 +0530; 3s ago<br>
    Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes<br>  Process: 21234 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET
```

Tried adding `Environment="KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS=--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --fail-swap-on=false"`  to `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` as described [here](http://Active:%20activating%20(auto-restart)%20(Result:%20exit-code)%20since%20Thu%202021-11-11%2010:50:49%20+0530;%203s%20ago%20%20%20%20%20%20Docs:%20https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes%20%20%20Process:%2021234%20ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet%20$KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS%20$KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS%20$KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS%20$KUBELET), but still its not working properly.

Also removed `--port=0` comment in above mentioned manifests and tried restarting,still same result.

**Edit:** This issue was due to `kubelet` certificate expired and fixed following [these](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2054#issuecomment-606916146) steps. If someone faces this issue, make sure `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem` certificate and key values are base64 encoded when placing on `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`

Many other suggested `kubeadm init` again. But this cluster was created using `kubespray` no manually added nodes.

We have baremetal k8 running on Ubuntu 18.04.
K8: v1.18.8

We would like to know any debugging and fixing suggestions.

PS:
When we try to `telnet 10.233.0.1 443` from any node, first attempt fails and second attempt success.

Edit: Found this in `kubelet` service logs

```
Nov 10 17:35:05 node1 kubelet[1951]: W1110 17:35:05.380982    1951 docker_sandbox.go:402] failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: networkPlugin cni failed on the status hook for pod "app-7b54557dd4-bzjd9_default": unexpected command output nsenter: cannot open /proc/12311/ns/net: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem after updating to k8s v1.22.2 from v1.21 :/

Comment: I noticed that you are setting the flag --fail-swap-on=false, but can you give a try with running the command **sudo swapoff -a** and do **restart kubelet**. If it didn't work then try by changing the cgroup to systemd in docker. To do that edit the /etc/docker/daemon.json file to '{ "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"] }'. And restart docker with **sudo systemctl restart docker**.For more info refer to the [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54542#issuecomment-850763432).

Comment: @ChandraKiranPasumarti Well still kubelet is not starting, even after `docker restart`

Comment: Can you check if zombie process are running on the nodes? Just `ps aux | grep 'Z'`

Comment: @AndD No Zombie process are shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting comment as the community wiki answer for better visibility

---

This issue was due to `kubelet` certificate expired and fixed following [these steps](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2054#issuecomment-606916146). If someone faces this issue, make sure `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem` certificate and key values are `base64` encoded when placing on `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`